# Hazelcast as Second level cache + distributed

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Can we use hazelcast as second level cache plus distributed cache. I want to configure entities to cache as second level cache and few collections as distributed. Could you please direct me to some example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Barvepan, you can check this project of mine: https://github.com/gokhanoner/seajug-demo

It uses Hazelcast as Hibernate 2nd level cache, distributed object cache + distributed session cache.

You can find separate examples in Hazelcast samples repo:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration